# Conteúdo do tamanho da tela do browser

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Em muitos sites de portfólio, podemos ver sections (geralmente com imagens) que ocupam o espaço exato do browser do usuário, como [este site aqui](http://html5up.net/big-picture).

Procurei mas não encontrei em nenhum lugar como realizar este efeito de manter várias sections do mesmo tamanho do browser. Como posso desenvolver algo semelhante utilizando CSS3 e Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para garantir que uma `section` usa a largura toda do browser pode fazer assim:

```
section {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px; // caso queira defenir a altura via CSS e não pela quantidade de conteúdo
}
```

Partindo do presuposto que é descendente direto do body ou que o seu parente tem `width: 100%;` também, sem `padding` ou `margin`.

Para garantir que cada section usa a altura completa do ecrã pode usar CSS (em browsers modernos) com o Viewport height:

```
section {
    height:100vh;
}
```

Ou usar jQuery:

```
$('section').css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');
```

E para garantir que todo o espaço é usado precisa fazer um reset às margens. No minimo seria:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/09xfjswo/1/show/

<sub>(retire o `/show/` do url para ver o código)</sub>

Comment: no exemplo que você deu, as sections não estão ocupando o espaço do browser... estou utilizando o chrome

Comment: @Vinícius é assim que quer? http://jsfiddle.net/09xfjswo/1/show/

Comment: Entendi! A largura das sections estão equivalentes a do browser. E para colocar a altura do browser nas sections?

Comment: @Vinícius juntei à resposta. Mas quer dizer que quer a altura do tamanho da janela?

Comment: Exatamente Sérgio! Com este código que você colocou na resposta, consigo então um efeito semelhante ao exemplo da pergunta? Estas são as melhores práticas? Existe algum problema de cross-browsers?